# GradientTape().gradient() returns None with tendons being watched - Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2, and am trying to calculate the gradient using two tensors.

`y_pred` is of shape `(None, 1)` and `averaged_samples` is a list of length 2 in which each element is of shape `(None, 16834, 1)`. However, the gradient always returns `[None, None]`. One thing to note is that `tf.gradients` works correctly with eager execution disabled (instead of gradient tape).

My code is:

```py
# Image input (real sample)
        real_audio = Input(shape=(self.a*16384, 1))

        # Noise input
        z_disc = Input(shape=(self.a, self.latent_dim))
        # Generate image based of noise (fake sample)
        fake_audio = self.generator(z_disc)

        # Discriminator determines validity of the real and fake images
        fake = self.critic(fake_audio)
        valid = self.critic(real_audio)

        # Construct weighted average between real and fake images
        interpolated_audio = RandomWeightedAverage()([real_audio, fake_audio])
        # Determine validity of weighted sample
        validity_interpolated = self.critic(interpolated_audio)

        # Use Python partial to provide loss function with additional
        # 'averaged_samples' argument
        partial_gp_loss = partial(self.gradient_penalty_loss,
                          averaged_samples=interpolated_audio)
        partial_gp_loss.__name__ = 'gradient_penalty' # Keras requires function names

        self.critic_model = Model(inputs=[real_audio, z_disc],
                            outputs=[valid, fake, validity_interpolated])
        self.critic_model.compile(loss=[self.wasserstein_loss,
                                              self.wasserstein_loss,
                                              partial_gp_loss],
                                        optimizer=optimizer,
                                        loss_weights=[1, 1, 10])

def gradient_penalty_loss(y_true, y_pred, _averaged_samples):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(y_pred)
        tape.watch(averaged_samples[0])
        tape.watch(averaged_samples[1])
        gradient = tape.gradient(y_pred, averaged_samples)
```

Comment: I believe you need to have the tape since the beginning of the calculations of `y_pred`. You can't just use it to get the gradients, you must let it see how you built `y_pred` from those other vars.

Comment: Indeed, you should move your code within the scope of the gradient tape so it can register the dependencies between graph leaves and prediction. I don't think watching `y_pred` is necessary

Answer (score 0):

The use of `tape` as explained in tutorials is:

- Let all operations that build `y_pred` inside the `with` block. (I presume the tape needs to see how you calculate it in order to know how to differentiate it)
- Get the gradients outside the with block.

Example:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = model_or_function_whatever(inputs)

gradients = tape.gradient(loss, allWeights)
```

It's not necessary to have a "model" exactly, but it's necessary that you calculate `y_pred` inside the block, at least from the point where `averaged_samples` start participating.

Comment: Would you mind please suggesting how I would implement what you suggest in the crude code extracted I just included in my question edit? Hopefully it will help clarify how it works. Thanks

Comment: What is `averaged_samples`? It does not participate anywhere, how do you expect gradients for it? What is `partial`?